# Is it possible to automatically run a batch file whenever I run my application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I want to clear a log file and run a separate application to display the logs whenever I run the application through Visual Studio*. I can script that into a batch file, but I want it to run every time I start the application. How can I do this?

*to clarify, I only want to run the batch file when I'm debugging in the dev environment.

Comment: Every time the application runs, or every time you run it using the Run command from VS?

Comment: Only from VS - thanks, I've updated the post to clarify.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to execute a batch file which in turn runs your program? I don't know how that would work in debugging mode though.

Comment: IsDebuggerPresent. Note that changing behavior based on whether you are being debugged is not recommended, because it can result in bugs that go away if you try to debug them. Better would be to have a command line switch that says whether you want to clear the logs.